# secure connection failed

Tags: support

I use Mozilla Firefox 52.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.4

This error message is a permanent nuisance when using tex.stackexchange

[image]

Is it a bug on your side or should I fix anything on my side?

Could the hint be here:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any problems here on Windows with Firefox 60.0.2. What about clearing your browser cash and all that stuff (and upgrading)?

Comment: I don't have a problem with Linux (Fedora) and Firefox 60.0.1.

Comment: this problem hits me sometimes, especially on my office workstation (windows professional, behind a heavy firewall).  it's sometimes able to be reversed by explicitly re-entering the url with `https`.  on my (ancient, out-of-date) macbook, if it happens with firefox, it can sometimes be reversed by switching to a newer, different browser.  but if those tactics don't work, then notifying the target site that their certificate is out of date is likely the only solution i've come up with.